# Looking for generic way to implement function in base class

Tags: c#, functional-programming, base-class, generics

I'm trying to do a simple implementation of the Specification pattern in my domain layer.

If I have a static class full of specifications like this:

```
public static class FooSpecifications
{
  public static Func<Foo, bool> IsSuperhuman
  {
    get
    {
      return foo => foo.CanShootLasersOutOfItsEyes && foo.CanFly;
    }
  }
}
```

Then I can do marvellous things like this:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> foos = GetAllMyFoos();
var superFoos = foos.Where(FooSpecifications.IsSuperhuman);
```

I can also add bool method to Foo to determine if a particular instance meets a specification:

```
public bool Meets(Func<Foo, bool> specification)
{
  return specification.Invoke(this);
}
```

Given that Foo, like all my domain entities, extends DomainObject, is there a way I can put a generic implementation of Meets() into the DomainObject to save me implementing Meets() separately in every entity?

Comment: Tip: you can use Predicate<T> instead of Func<T, bool>.

Comment: @Paul: You can, but the trend in more recent versions of the framework, and especially LINQ, is to use `Func<T,bool>` rather than `Predicate<T>`.

Comment: @LukeH: Interesting, did not know this (obviously) thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this...

```
    public abstract class DomainObj<T> // T - derived type
        where T : DomainObj<T>
    {
        public bool Meets(Func<T, bool> specification)
        {
            return specification.Invoke((T) this);
        }
    }

    public class Foo : DomainObj<Foo> {}

    public class Bar : DomainObj<Bar> {}       

        Func<Foo, bool> foospec = x => true;
        Func<Bar, bool> barspec = x => true;

        var foo = new Foo();
        var bar = new Bar();
        foo.Meets(foospec);
        foo.Meets(barspec); // won't compile because of mismatched types of spec and object instance
```

**EDIT**

Maybe it will be better to translate Meet method to extension. This will remove need in type parameter.

```
    public abstract class DomainObj
    {
    }

    public static class DomainObjExtensions
    {
        public static bool Meets<T>(this T obj, Func<T, bool> f)
            where T : DomainObj
        {
            return f(obj);
        }
    }

    public class Foo : DomainObj {}

    public class Bar : DomainObj {}

    Func<Foo, bool> foospec = x => true;
    Func<Bar, bool> barspec = x => true;

    var foo = new Foo();
    var bar = new Bar();
    foo.Meets(foospec);
    foo.Meets(barspec); // error
```

Comment: What are the braces after the derived class declarations? When I put them in, I start getting 'namespace cannot contain members' compiler errors.

Comment: Either way, in the derived class the compiler doesn't recognise the DomainObject type, even though they're in the same namespace.

Comment: My bad: I had pasted some of your code but not noticed you were using DomainObj instead of DomainObject.

Comment: This appears to work but now I have another problem. How do I cast a derived type back to DomainObject<T>?

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean cast derived type to DomainObject, rather cast an object to DomainObject.